# How do I get a list of open network connections for a process in C#?

Tags: c#, networking

ie like the TCP/IP   tab in process explorer : 
[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_Eb_GMBgSIlY/SmZwF1QEqgI/AAAAAAAABiU/frQVozm2nwc/TCP-tab.JPG](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_Eb_GMBgSIlY/SmZwF1QEqgI/AAAAAAAABiU/frQVozm2nwc/TCP-tab.JPG)

I know how to get all open connections for the machine - but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to tie them to a process. Is there an API to do this in .net - or some creative  use of PInvoke perhaps ?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use P/Invoke:

[GetTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366026(VS.85).aspx) can be used to get all the TCP connections.

```
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll")] 
public static extern int GetTcpTable( ... );
```

This [article](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=20989) has example code.

Comment: thanks.  googling a bit for GetTcpTable brought me to this codeproject article
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iphlpapi.aspx?display=Print
which wraps the PInvokes in a slightly nicer .net API